# Eliminate productory

Tags: recurrence-relations, products

I want to write a general formula of:
$$ a_n= a_0\prod^{n}_{i=1} \frac{2i+4}{i(i+1)}$$
I want to write $a_n$ in terms of $n$ only, is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

One may write
$$
a_n= a_0\prod^{n}_{i=1} \frac{2i+4}{i(i+1)}=a_0\frac{\prod^{n}_{i=1} 2(i+2)}{\prod^{n}_{i=1} i\prod^{n}_{i=1} (i+1)}=a_0\frac{2^{n}(n+2)!}{2(n!)^2 \cdot (n+1)}=a_0\frac{2^{n-1}(n+2)}{n!}.
$$